# turn off WooCommerce for a site in a multi site environment

Tags: plugins, multisite

I've just installed [P3 (Plugin Performance Profiler)](http://wordpress.org/plugins/p3-profiler/) and it shows that WooCommerce & WooCommerce Subscriptions are active on every one of my subdomain multi sites.

How do I turn plugins off on on a site by site basis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugins are not like Themes were you need to network activate them to make them available on each site.

If you network activate a plugin, it will be switched ON for all network sites.

If you wish to allow each site to decide if they wish to activate or deactivate the plugin, then network deactivate the plugin in network admin.